# VIPER architecture: submodules in a module

Tags: ios, swift, viper-architecture

I have a VIPER module (`SubjectList`) in which I want to have a more generic `HeaderModule`, with a `SubjectListCollectionModule` and a `BlockModule`. At what point would I logically add the `HeaderModule`?

I could include the modules in the `SubjectListViewModel`, but I could also render them in the `SubjectListView`, instantiate them via Interface Builder, use `xibs`. What is recommended?

Answer (score 2):

I recently made a sample project which is built using the VIPER architecture with the help of the codegen tool called Generamba.

Here is the project:
  https://github.com/dimklo/ViperSample

In this project you can find the module called News. This module has two submodules named NewsTable and NewsFilter. These submodules are presented from the News module router in methods `presentNewsFilterModule` and `presentNewsListModule`.

The submodule creation code there is not very easy to follow but maybe it will help you somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Use of xib is a good option, but I suggest you go with Interface Builder. That'll be a more well-to-do thing with VIPER.

Comment: You need to rephrase this, as it's currently written you said that xibs and IB are different approaches.

Comment: there will be different approaches for calling a view controller for both.